# Tinyos reception after second reply doesn't work

Tags: tinyos, nesc

I'm in trouble with my nesC code. In my code I send a first packet using `AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &packet, sizeof(rd_message))`.

After that, when a message is received in function `event message_t* Receive.receive(message_t* bufPtr, void* payload, uint8_t len){` a reply is generated and sent successfully, but the other nodes are not able to receive the reply. In particular I have to process a RREP reply, following the basics of DSR protocol. 
This is my code:

```
implementation{


/**********************Variables used*****************************/
short phase = 0;
message_t packet;
bool locked;

event void Boot.booted(){
    dbg("Boot", "Node %hhu booted\n", TOS_NODE_ID);
    call AMControl.start(); 


}

  [cut]

event void MilliTimer.fired(){
    /*This contains the discovery message*/
    rd_message *rreq = NULL;

    if (phase == 0){
        //Route discovery phase
        rreq = (rd_message *) call Packet.getPayload(&packet, (int) NULL);


        if(call AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &packet, sizeof(rd_message)) == SUCCESS){
        //locked = TRUE;

        }
        return;
    }

}


event message_t* Receive.receive(message_t* bufPtr, void* payload, uint8_t len){
    rd_message *received_mex = NULL;  
    rd_message *reply_mex = NULL;

    int i,j;

    received_mex = (rd_message*) payload;   //cast to rd_message

      if (received_mex->type == RREQ){
          reply_mex = (rd_message*) call Packet.getPayload(&packet, (int) NULL);  //reply packet is created.
        if (received_mex->sender_id == TOS_NODE_ID){
          //The original sender received its RREQ. Stopping the forward procedure
          return bufPtr;   //FIXME: see if it's correct to return null here
        }

        //RREQ message case 1: I am not the receiver_id
        if (received_mex->receiver_id != TOS_NODE_ID){

        }
        else if (received_mex->receiver_id == TOS_NODE_ID){
          //I am the receiver of the RREQ message. I can now reply with a RREP

        }


        if (call AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &packet, sizeof(rd_message)) == SUCCESS) {
                dbg("dsr", "packet sent\n");    
                //locked = TRUE;
            }
        else{
          dbg("dsr", "failed to send reply packet.\n");

        }


      }
      else if (received_mex->type == RREP){
       //DO SOMETHING WITH CHE NEW RECEIVED MESSAGE HERE

      }

    return bufPtr;


}


  event void AMSend.sendDone(message_t* bufPtr, error_t error) {
    if (&packet == bufPtr) {
      //locked = FALSE;
    }
  }
```

I removed all the logic from the code to focus on the message exchange calls. I hope that someone can help me... thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinyOS follows almost everywhere a *ownership* discipline: at any point in time, every
"memory object" - a piece of memory, typically a whole variable or a single array element - should be owned by a single module. A command like `send` is said to pass ownership of its msg argument from caller to callee.

The main problem of your code is that in the `Receive.receive` event you are using the `packet` variable in two ways:

- as outgoing packet by calling `call AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &packet, sizeof(rd_message))`
- as buffer for the next incoming packet by executing `return bufPtr;`

the result of this code is unpredictable (since receiving a packet will corrupt the outgoing packet). To solve your problem, you should use a `Pool<message_t>` component. The typical pseudocode for a program like yours is like:

1. receive (m):
2. if I don't need to process this message, return m
3. if my free packet list is empty, return m
4. else

   1. process/forward m
   2. return entry from free packet list

This is a rough implementation of a module that uses `Pool<message_t>` as list of free packets to manage communication:

```
module Foo
{
    /* this is our free packet list */
    uses interface Pool<message_t>;
    uses interface Receive;
    uses interface AMSend;
}

implementation
{

event void MilliTimer.fired()
{
    message_t *packet;
    /* get a free packet */
    packet = Pool.get();
    if (packet)
    {
        /* code to send the packet */
    }
}

event void AMSend.sendDone(message_t *msg, error_t error)
{
    /* the send function ended, put back the packet in the free packet pool */
    /* check here if msg was taken from Pool */
    call Pool.put(msg);
}

event message_t* Receive.receive(message_t* msg, void* payload, uint8_t len)
{
    if (!haveToProcess(msg))
        return msg; // don't have to process this message
    if (Pool.empty())
        return msg; // memory exahusted;
    /* ... */
    /* code that processes the packet */
    call AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, msg, sizeof(rd_message));
    /* return a free message_t* as buffer to store the next received packet */
    return Pool.get();
}

}
```

If you don't like `Pool`, you can use a `message_t` array as circular buffer. Take a look at the [BaseStation](http://code.google.com/p/tinyos-main/source/browse/trunk/apps/BaseStation/BaseStationP.nc) code for a hint on how to do so.

For more details, I suggest you to read the [TinyOS programming book](http://csl.stanford.edu/~pal/pubs/tos-programming-web.pdf), especially section 3.5.1.

As for your comment:

```
return bufPtr;   //FIXME: see if it's correct to return null here
```

you can **never** return `NULL` in a receive event, since TinyOS needs always a buffer to store incoming packets.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, things are now clear. Of course I have to study in detail TinyOS development and understand well how to handle situations like this. Ancora grazie mille!!